# Send push message to multiple devices

Tags: php, ios, push-notification

According to an article, the author provided a PHP script below to send a push message to one device ($deviceToken). How can I send a push message to multiple devices instead of one device only?

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = 'de641706f194fa32169dcd8297309153bb6b4de838f9b7cb7cb83c0e24b6609b';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'ibpspass';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'New promotion is updated!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Make it a function and simply iterate over the tokens? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to maintain a database of devices, and send the notification to each one. That's why the API is designed for high volume, small size messages.